# Merge nested array with unique element in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

How can I achieve this without using any library? 
I have tried it with some ES6 function but it ended up duplicating some items in the array. It should return unique especially when there is no *child array* in the array

I have three array variables:

**data1** = first data

**data2** = variable to be merge with **data1**

**data3** = result of the merged variables

```
        let data1 = [{
            "document_id": 12264,
            "detail_info": [{
                "id": 745,
                "lot_no": "X12345",
              },
              {
                "id": 744,
                "lot_no": "Z12345",
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "document_id": 12226,
            "detail_info": [{
                "id": 738,
                "lot_no": "B12345",
              },
              {
                "id": 739,
                "lot_no": "C12345",
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "document_id": 12221,
            "detail_info": []
          }
        ]

        let data2 = [{
            "document_id": 12264,
            "detail_info": [{
                "id": 744,
                "lot_no": "Z12345",
              },
              {
                "id": 743,
                "lot_no": "L12345",
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "document_id": 12226,
            "detail_info": [{
              "id": 739,
              "lot_no": "C12345",
            }]
          },
          {
            "document_id": 12229,
            "detail_info": [{
              "id": 741,
              "lot_no": "E12345",
            }]
          },
          {
            "document_id": 10095,
            "detail_info": []
          }
        ]

//**This should be the result**
      let data3=[
      {
        "document_id": 12264,
        "detail_info": [
          {
            "id": 745,
            "lot_no": "X12345",
          },
          {
            "id": 744,
            "lot_no": "Z12345",
          },
          {
            "id": 743,
            "lot_no": "L12345",
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "document_id": 12226,
        "detail_info": [
          {
            "id": 738,
            "lot_no": "B12345",
          },
          {
            "id": 739,
            "lot_no": "C12345",
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "document_id": 12221,
        "detail_info": []
      },
      {
        "document_id": 12229,
        "detail_info": [
          {
            "id": 741,
            "lot_no": "E12345",
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "document_id": 10095,
        "detail_info": []
      }
    ]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First concatenate `data1` and `data2` into a single array (`[...data1, ...data2]`).

Then with [`Array.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce), generate a dictionary whose keys are all possible `document_id` found in the array.

Inside `reduce`, when an entry already exists for a `document_id`, then you have to merge the `detail_info` together. Create an array of all `detail_info` from the existing entry and the current item and remove the duplicates using a `Set` that you generate from the `detail_info.id`, then map this `Set` of ids to the the corresponding `detail_info` entries.

Finally, convert the dictionary to an array with [`Object.values()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values):

```js
const data1 = [
  { "document_id": 12264, someData: 'hello', "detail_info": [{ "id": 745, "lot_no": "X12345" },  { "id": 744, "lot_no": "Z12345" }] },
  { "document_id": 12226, "detail_info": [{ "id": 738, "lot_no": "B12345" }, { "id": 739, "lot_no": "C12345" }] },
  { "document_id": 12221, "detail_info": [] }
];

const data2 = [
  { "document_id": 12264, "detail_info": [{ "id": 744, "lot_no": "Z12345" }, { "id": 743, "lot_no": "L12345" }] },
  { "document_id": 12226, "detail_info": [{ "id": 739, "lot_no": "C12345" }] },
  { "document_id": 12229, "detail_info": [{ "id": 741, "lot_no": "E12345" }] },
  { "document_id": 10095, "detail_info": [] }
];

const distinctById = arr => [...new Set(arr.map(({ id }) => id))]
  .map(id => arr.find(info => info.id === id))

const data3 = Object.values([...data1, ...data2].reduce((acc, x) => {
  acc[x.document_id] = acc[x.document_id] || { ...x, detail_info: [] };
  acc[x.document_id].detail_info = distinctById([...acc[x.document_id].detail_info, ...x.detail_info]);
  return acc;
}, {}));

console.log(data3);
```

If you want to keep your `detail_info` array ordered by insertion, do this:

```js
const distinctById = arr => {
  const uniqueIds = new Set(arr.map(({ id }) => id));
  return arr.filter(({ id }) => uniqueIds.delete(id));
}

console.log(distinctById([{ id: 5 }, { id: 4 }, { id: 5 }, { id: 3 }, { id: 4 }]))
```

Comment: It's working. Thank you so much, how can I add more for the final result if I have other than element beside **document_id** ?

Comment: Happy that it helps! I will update the answer to handle this case as well

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, it's totally working. I would like to ask if this way is faster/better for doing DOM manipulation, because I am using it in React.js' state, I am updating the state on it.

Comment: Since React uses a Virtual DOM, it will only update the parts of the DOM that changed, so the performance impact of changing all the state should not be a problem, since each rendering loop will actually rerender the whole page, but only patch the DOM where there are differences.

Comment: I tried your latest answer, and it's working. But do you have any idea how can I sort this? Like the last item/s added should be in the last index of the array.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to combine two arrays, use `concat`:

```
let data3 = data1.concat(data2);
```

Comment: When I do concat, duplication is still there.